# How can I join tables in SQL based upon the row that was joined before it?

Tags: sql, mysql, join

I want to estimate the average time it takes individual to return the borrowed items  they actually return. The action of borrowing and returning the same item comes up as different lending number so i have to estimate the first return based on the earliest time the item was borrowed within 30 days.

```
SELECT 
borrow.lend_num, 
borrow.item, 
borrow.borrower,
borrow.credit_deduction,
borrow.type, 
borrow.date, 
borrow.BORROWED_order,
returns.lend_num, 
returns.item, 
returns.borrower,
returns.credit_deduction, 
returns.type, 
returns.date, 
returns.BORROWED_order, 
 DATEDIFF(returns.dat_time,purchases.dat_time)
FROM CTE AS borrow  
RIGHT JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM CTE
   WHERE type = 'RETURNED')  AS returns
ON borrow.item= returns.item 
AND borrow.borrower = returns.borrower 
AND returns.date > borrow.date 
AND DATEDIFF(returns.date,borrow.date) < 15 FROM CTE AS borrowers 
WHERE borrow.type = 'BORROWED' 
AND returns.type = 'RETURNED';
```

Here's an example of the dataset

```
lend# item borrower credit_dedct type  date       Borrowed_ordr RTRNDd_order   
15    167   5     -26       BORROWED 3/9/14 5:58      1       NULL  
19    167   5     -26       BORROWED 3/9/14 5:58      2       NULL 
26    167   5     -26       BORROWED 3/9/14 5:58      3*          NULL 
31    167   5     26        RETURNED 3/9/14 9:58     NULL      1 
37    167   5     26        RETURNED 3/9/14 9:58     NULL      2 
42    167   5     -26       BORROWED 3/13/14 5:21     4       NULL 
48    167   5     -26       BORROWED 3/24/14 17:33    5       NULL 
53    167   5     26        RETURNED 3/24/14 13:27   NULL      3* 
59    167   5     26        RETURNED 3/25/14 12:31   NULL      4
61    167   5     -26       BORROWED 4/11/14 13:31   6    
64    167   5     26        RETURNED 4/17/14 19:31   NULL      5
```

** NOTICE HERE THAT PURCHASE 3 DOES NOT GO WITH RETURN 3 B/C ITS > 15 DAYS APART** So, return-3 needs to go with borrowed-4 AND return-4 needs needs to go with borrowed-5, etcv.
HERE IS WHAT I WANT IT TO LOOK LIKE:

```
return  Rtrn_order rtrn_time  borrow  borrow_time BORROWED_order time_diff  
RETURNED    1        3/9/14 9:58  BORROWED  3/9/14 5:58     1       0 dys
RETURNED    2        3/9/14 9:58  BORROWED  3/9/14 5:58     2       0 dys
RETURNED    3       3/11/14 13:27 BORROWED  3/13/14 5:21    4   2dys
RETURNED    4      3/11/14 13:31  BORROWED  3/24/14 17:33   5   13dys
RETURNED    5      4/17/14        BORROWED   4/11/14 13:31  6    6dys
```

You can see here that the first return joins with  the earliest borrow **within 15 days** and then the 2nd earliest return joins with the 2nd earliest borrow. **There are times with more than 15 days with no returns, as can be seen at the bottom of the sample**

I tried making the table into 2 tables, a borrow table and a return table, then I joined them together...
But I couldn't figure out a join condition that would only join one return to the earliest possible purchase that the item could have been returned...Help requested. thanks!

Comment: `LAG` i think is what you'll need https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-lag-function/

Comment: There's no `FROM <table>` to right-join. I think the `borrow` table is missing in your query.

Comment: Please don't link to images, add all relevant information to your question as editable text - then someone can copy it if they want to try a solution (plus all the information is then viewable in one place rather than spread across multiple pages)

Comment: @Nathan_Sav No, that doesn't help me. The joining of the CTE table into tables creates too many rows without giving preference

Comment: Why does borrow #5 and return #5 not print out with your results?

Comment: @RossBush I edited the dataset to better reflect the problem. Thanks